# i need vertical autoscroll <ul> list with mouse movement using java script jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help on making the list items moveable with the mouse movement .
if the user just move  the mouse  cursor vertically **upward** over the list then the list should be scroll downward and if the user move  the mouse  cursor **downward** over the list then the list should be scroll upward and if the user

```html
<body>

<ul style="height:200px; width:18%;overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
        <li>Henry Christensen</li>
        <li>Imelda Silva</li>
        <li>Marah Mueller</li>
        <li>Holly Fitzpatrick</li>
        <li>Lamar Flynn</li>
        <li>Jameson Davidson</li>
        <li>Harper Lynn</li>
        <li>Keith Woods</li>
        <li>Cally Dominguez</li>
        <li>Carter Gould</li>
        <li>Brenna Sutton</li>
        <li>Robert Vang</li>
        <li>Lane Shepard</li>
        <li>Ila Shepard</li>
        <li>Madaline Mccarthy</li>
        <li>Raya King</li>
        <li>Tara Schroeder</li>
        <li>Paloma Bryan</li>
        <li>Trevor Heath</li>
        <li>Raymond Vega</li>
        <li>Nyssa Mcleod</li>
        <li>Zachary Deleon</li>
        <li>Guy Morales</li>
        <li>Gannon Kline</li>
        <li>Clare Floyd</li>
      </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below listens for a mouse move event within the element, and checks the difference between the current and last mouse Y values. It uses that to scroll with the `scrollTop` function.

The `mouseleave` listener deletes the stored mouse Y value, meaning that the scroll position won't lock to what it last was when your mouse leaves and re-enters.

Hope this helps!

```js
var ly;

$(function() {
  $("#list").mousemove(function(e) {
      if (ly) {
        $("#list").scrollTop($("#list").scrollTop()+ly-e.clientY);
        ly = e.clientY;
      } else {
        ly = e.clientY;
      };
  });
  $("#list").mouseleave(function() {
    ly = null;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<ul id="list" style="height:200px; width:18%;overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
        <li>Henry Christensen</li>
        <li>Imelda Silva</li>
        <li>Marah Mueller</li>
        <li>Holly Fitzpatrick</li>
        <li>Lamar Flynn</li>
        <li>Jameson Davidson</li>
        <li>Harper Lynn</li>
        <li>Keith Woods</li>
        <li>Cally Dominguez</li>
        <li>Carter Gould</li>
        <li>Brenna Sutton</li>
        <li>Robert Vang</li>
        <li>Lane Shepard</li>
        <li>Ila Shepard</li>
        <li>Madaline Mccarthy</li>
        <li>Raya King</li>
        <li>Tara Schroeder</li>
        <li>Paloma Bryan</li>
        <li>Trevor Heath</li>
        <li>Raymond Vega</li>
        <li>Nyssa Mcleod</li>
        <li>Zachary Deleon</li>
        <li>Guy Morales</li>
        <li>Gannon Kline</li>
        <li>Clare Floyd</li>
      </ul>
</body>
```